# Trying to update Java on Linux (Linux installed by Crouton)

Tags: software-installation, java, crouton

I wanted to download Minecraft on Linux so I downloaded Java 7, because anything over Java 7 says

```
Could not find
```

so I installed Java 7, but when I try to update Java by entering:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

it doesn't work. Neither does

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

Do I need to install something else for Java to work?
I can't add any PPA'S at all, no matter what!

Please help!

Comment: Why can't you add any PPAs? It should work if they have contents for your hardware architecture. If not then obviously adding them does nothing. But why do you think you need a PPA for Java? I think you should install OpenJDK?

Answer (score 0):

I found out yesterday that 'webupd8team' is a private repository, managed by one guy. Exactly one year ago there was a similar problem, and that was a license issue as I understand.

I fixed it with an answer provided here -> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686

`cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|' oracle-java8-installer.*`

`sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|' oracle-java8-installer.*`

`sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ=.*|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|' oracle-java8-installer.*`

`sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|' oracle-java8-installer.*`

And then finally:

`sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer`

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I already  fixed the error, I already had the latest java version by opening the Java.deb file with a package installer instead of installing java by terminal.